# onItemClickListener is not working for the customListadapter

Tags: android, list, listview, onitemclicklistener

onItemClickListener is not working for the customListadapter.. some one pls help me.Here is full code.I ve set on itemclick listener for the listview. But it is not working.

enter code here`BuddiesActivity.class

```
public class BuddiesActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * list view
     */
    ListView listViewFriendsDetails;
    /**
     * adapter for list out the friendsDetails
     */
    ListViewCustomeAdapter detailsAdapter;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflaterObject = getMenuInflater();
        inflaterObject.inflate(R.menu.buddiesmenu, menu);
        /*
         * to change the colour of menu background
         */
        getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
                    AttributeSet attrs) {
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {
                    try {
                        LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
                        final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);
                        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                // set the background drawable
                                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

                                // set the text color
                                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);

                            }
                        });
                        return view;
                    } catch (InflateException e) {
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    } finally {
                        Log.i(Constants.DETAILS_WORKSHEET_ACTIVITY,
                                "menu colour changed");
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreatePanelMenu(featureId, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.birthday:

            detailsAdapter = new ListViewCustomeAdapter(this,
                    DatabaseOperation.friendsBirthdayDetailsArrayListObject
                            .size(),
                    DatabaseOperation.friendsBirthdayDetailsArrayListObject,
                    true);

            listViewFriendsDetails.setAdapter(detailsAdapter);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(BuddiesActivity.this,
    // DetailsActivity.class);
    // detailsIntent
    // .setAction(DatabaseOperation.friendsDetailsArrayListObject
    // .get(position).getEmailId());
    // startActivity(detailsIntent);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        /*
         * Listing the songs and its details
         */
        listViewFriendsDetails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        detailsAdapter = new ListViewCustomeAdapter(this,
                DatabaseOperation.friendsDetailsArrayListObject.size(),
                DatabaseOperation.friendsDetailsArrayListObject, false);
        listViewFriendsDetails.setAdapter(detailsAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listViewFriendsDetails);

        listViewFriendsDetails
                .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        System.out
                                .println("buttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt");
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "call");
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Message");
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Find him/her");
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Find his/her home");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
        try {
            info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.e("", "bad menuInfo", e);
            return false;
        }

        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "id = "
                        + DatabaseOperation.friendsDetailsArrayListObject.get(
                                info.position).getFirstName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
}


This my adapter to list the items
ListViewCustomAdapter.class


public class ListViewCustomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
    /**
     * normal selection or birthday selection
     */
    Boolean IS_BIRTHDAY;
    /**
     * Information of the friendsdetails from the database
     */
    ArrayList<FriendsDetails> friendsDetailsInList = new ArrayList<FriendsDetails>();
    public Context context;
    public Context con;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListViewCustomeAdapter(Context context, int count,
            ArrayList<FriendsDetails> friendsDetailsArryListObject,
            Boolean IS_BIRTHDAY) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.IS_BIRTHDAY = IS_BIRTHDAY;
        friendsDetailsInList = friendsDetailsArryListObject;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return friendsDetailsInList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * @author Anitha
     * 
     */
    public static class ViewHolder {

        /**
         * Email Id
         */
        TextView emaiIdView;
        /**
         * First name
         */
        TextView txtViewTitle;
        /**
         * Status
         */
        TextView statusTextView;
        /**
         * The phone icon
         */
        ImageView phoneIcon;
        /**
         * The home icon
         */
        ImageView homeIcon;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        FriendsDetails particularFriendsInfo = friendsDetailsInList
                .get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitemrow, null);
            holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitle);
            holder.statusTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.status);
            holder.emaiIdView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.emailId);
            holder.phoneIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.mobileAvailable);
            holder.homeIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.addressAvailable);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        /*
         * If the person has no mobile number and address
         */
        if (particularFriendsInfo.getAddress() == null) {
            holder.homeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.mobileiconrestricted);
        }
        if (particularFriendsInfo.getMobileNumber() == null) {
            holder.phoneIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.homerestricted);
        }
        holder.txtViewTitle.setText(particularFriendsInfo.getFirstName());
        holder.emaiIdView.setText(particularFriendsInfo.getEmailId());
        if (!IS_BIRTHDAY)
            holder.statusTextView.setText(particularFriendsInfo.getStatus());
        else
            holder.statusTextView.setText(particularFriendsInfo.getBirthday());
        convertView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
        // }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

This is my xml where it it contains the view of each row in listview.
listitemrow.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@layout/itemselector"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="5dip">

    <ImageView 
    android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="50dip" 
        android:layout_height="50dip" 
        android:id="@+id/imgViewLogo" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="center">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView 
    android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/txtViewTitle" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewLogo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip">
    </TextView>
    <ImageView
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/mobileicon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtViewTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/mobileAvailable" 
    />
    <ImageView
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/home"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mobileAvailable"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/addressAvailable" 
    />
    <TextView 
    android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#606060"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/emailId" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgViewLogo"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtViewTitle"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip">
    </TextView>  
    <TextView
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/emailId" 
    android:layout_below="@id/txtViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:textColor="#606060"

    />

</RelativeLayout>


listview.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:listSelector="@layout/itemselector"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <ListView

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: istViewFriendsDetails.setOnItemClickListener(this).. implement listener add unimplemented methos and try

Answer (score 0):

Try setfocus to false programmatically to your imageview,textview,etc... like

```
                Button demo=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.demo);
                demo.setFocusable(false);
```

this is for buttonview set it for imageview and others

Comment: Except listview OnItemClickListener other functionalties are working huh?

Comment: Yeah everything is working fine. Other than that single click of listview

Comment: Actually i had the problem before,i solved it by the way i mentioned it before

Comment: I found the solution.Thanks for all your replies:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had to do in a similar situation.  Like you, I tried with *just* `android:focusable="false"` and it still didn't work.

So, what I did in the xml, for each imageview and textview in the row layout:

```
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

This assures that neither the keyboard or touchscreen can cause the focus to go to an item in the row rather than the row, and should enable the listener to work properly.

Comment: In that Customadapter I have given the oncreateContextmenu. If I removed that oncreatecontextmenu in getview , single onclick is working.So Inside that getview method which is there in the custom adapter set for onclick listener.Problem is solved:)